# Kolmogorov Smirnov test result vs paired t-test result

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, paired-data

I have a set of medical data which contains two samples taken in different time periods. Although the samples do not strictly contain the same people in each group, a large proportion in each group are the same.

My question, is that I have thus far computed a `ks.test` in R to compare the distributions of the two groups to determine if they're significantly different. This test was used since the data are not normally distributed and I wanted to check for more than just mean differences, but also look at the variance and shape of the distribution which is a result of the Kolmogorov Smirnov test (as opposed to the t test).

The result from this test was that the distributions are significantly different. Therefore, my question is, if I were to then filter for all of the people who appear in both groups and conduct a paired t test on the differences (which are normally distributed), would it automatically follow that the difference is significantly different to zero? In other words, is there a rule which says that if the distributions of the two groups are significantly different (using the sample of people who appear in both groups), then this must mean that the per person differences are significantly different to 0?

I understand that this wouldn't work the other way, i.e. if the paired t test was significant, then this wouldn't necessarily mean that the KS test would be significant.

Is that correct?

Comment: The ks test assumes independence. If you have the same people in both groups, the assumptions of the test don't hold.

Comment: I suppose I was generalising such that if the two samples are large enough (i.e. each over 50% of the population), then independence could not be guaranteed.. a push, I know.

Comment: the overlapping/nonoverlapping-samples part makes the question very weird/difficult (statistically speaking). The answer to "does significantly different distribution as measured by KS test -> significantly different means as measured by paired t-test" is no; consider two samples with the same mean but very different variances ...

Comment: Pedantry corner: Kolmogoroff was a common transliteration back in the day (say around 1950) but people always seem to go for Kolmogorov these days. What is certain is that Kolmogoroff implies Smirnoff too. Recommended: Kolmogorov-Smirnov. (No, I don't claim to speak or write Russian, but even so a quick Google shows that the last letter of each name  is the same character in the Cyrillic alphabet.)

Comment: I wonder if the spelling comes from Smirnoff vodka.

Comment: @sym246 No, there can be no such rule since the ks test detects more distributional  differences than just differences in means.